# how to display & hide window in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is it possible in matlab to show only those controls which are appropriate from the menu bar selection?

For example: if in my program, I have a menu in which user can choose A or B, then according to selection. Desired windows displayed or desired control are shown. The controls related to other one are not shown or window is not displayed.

OR how can I use microsoft windows form multi page control in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will setting the `visible` property of the relevant `uicontrol` to `off` do?

```
myfig = figure;
mybutton = uicontrol;
set(mybutton,'Visible','off'); % Hides mybutton
```

More on [`uicontrol` properties here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html).

---

Alternately, if it really is a tab-based interface you want, see the post [Putting the tab into a GUI](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/02/15/putting-the-tab-into-a-gui/) on the Mathworks blog "Mike on the MATLAB Desktop".